# Are there any consequences to starting Ashes of Ariandel after already beginning New Game+?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Finally beat Dark Souls 3 -- and loved it -- so much so that I started New Game Plus to retain my gear and mutilate all the invaders that gave me so much grief the first play-through.

However, I wouldn't say I'm bored with my clearly over-leveled character -- I see no reason to not continue my dominance into NG+2 (no such thing as OP in PvE, in my opinion :) -- but I *would* like to take on some new areas and enemies; so I want to grab Ashes of Ariandel DLC.

If I install the new Ashes of Ariandel DLC while currently playing NG+, am I going to lose access to areas/items/NPCs/etc. that would have been available only during the first play-through? Or is everything going to remain as if I never started NG+ (except of course the difficulty that comes with NG+)?

I'm just afraid I'm going to miss out on some items or side-quests because I started the DLC from NG+ instead of playing the DLC from NG (which was perhaps the developers' intent?)

Comment: The only NG+ related thing to know is that you need at least 2 game cycle to get every boss soul weapons from the DLC, which doesn't really matter as you need 3 cycles to get everything from the main game anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NG+ is, in a literal sense, a re-play of the game from start to finish with higher difficulty.

You are not going to miss anything due to NG+.

Ashes of Ariandel is also not a DLC that is accessible from the start, so the scaling of it is already for a character that is past the "tutorial" zones.

Comment: This is correct for DS1, but in DS3 you can find new items in new places (at least). So NG+ is NOT in a literal sence a re-play of the game.

Comment: While true, that is not relevant to this answer. The location of the DLC is irrelevant to the placement of items within the base game.

Answer (score 1):

NG+ upgrades enemies HP, damage, dropped souls, and a few rings that show up in the main game.

You won't lose anything by venturing to the DLC in NG+++, but keep in mind the bosses get exponentially harder for each NG+, which means you'll be fighting those bosses on hard mode. While your character is also OP, some bosses can get so strong they still OHKO you. I've done it a few times in the past Souls games (jumping to the DLCs straight from NG+(+) and had a much harder time clearing the DLC).